# Remove leading dots from start of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have some text that I need to target that has some leading dots, I have found some code that works with words and spacing between, but unable to get this to work for the leading dots. I have played with the regex, but it brakes things in a big way.

Here is what I have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('p').each(function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     $this.html($this.text().replace(/\b..\b/g, '<span style="display:none">..</span>'));
   });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xg3Ej/

Can anyone put me on the right path?

Comment: Precisely two dots, or any numbers? BTW See here for details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.` has a special meaning in regex, it will match any character. You need to escape it so that the regex matches a literal character `\.`.

```
$this.text().replace(/^(\.+)/g, '<span style="display:none">$1</span>')
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xg3Ej/6/

Answer (score 3):

Use `^` in your regex to look at the start of the string.

```
/^\.\./g
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xg3Ej/8/

Note: Thanks to Andrew Mackrodt for pointing out the escaping..

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove characters from the start use `^`, also escape the dot `\.`, otherwise `.` matches any character. Finally, use `+` to indicate match one or more dots.

```
/^\.+/g
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

This will capture the string starts with (..)

. => mean a single character in regex. Hence it is escaped using backslash.

example:

..jfghhfg

```
$this.html($this.text().replace(/^\.\./g, '<span style="display:none">..</span>'));
```

Here is the [demo](http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/3GK)

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying this simply:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('p').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
   $this.html($this.text().replace(/^\.{2}/g, ''));
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xg3Ej/9/

Answer (score 0):

This will work too http://jsfiddle.net/Xg3Ej/11/

```
$this.html($this.text().replace('..', '<span style="display:none">..</span>'));
```